# The relationship between the curvature of a curve and a circle

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, plane-curves

Let $c$ be a circle with constant curvature $k_c$, and the green curve $\alpha$ below with curvature at a point $x$ $k_{\alpha}(x)$

I would like to know if this inequality is true:

> $$k_{\alpha}(q)\lt k_c\lt k_{\alpha}(p)$$

is there anything I can say about $k_{\alpha}(r)$?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This inequality is not true in general. You can easily compare the curvature of these two curves at the points where one touches the other.
[image]

The curvature of the red curve is greater than of the curvature of the circle at their tangent point whereas the curvature of the curvature of the green one is less than the curvature of the circle at their tangent point.
One more example[image]

Comment: The original question was about two special points, p and q. Point P is returning to the circle and q is just crossing the circle from inside.

Comment: @user16409 I think he could not compare the curvatures at these points because there are many such points with different curvature values.

Comment: Do you think the curvature of the points p and q might be either greater or lesser than the curvature of the circle?

Comment: Yes. I think that.

Comment: I got it. @Semsem Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @user16409 you are welcome

Comment: One more question: is it possible to have a curve completely inside in a circle but with a point with less curvature than the circle? Thank you again!

Comment: Yes. every thing is possible except the points they are tangential to each other. Moreover, if the curve is a closed non-convex curve, it will have points with negative curvature while the circle will not.

Comment: I guess you have a problem including such curvature comparison. To get a good help from community, you may need to add the problem here.